# Get element value correctly(ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have AJAX script that generates div's with values

Here is code

```
<script>
$('#display').click(function () {
    $(".list").empty();
    var vacancyId = $("#vacancy").val();
    var model = {
        vacancyId: vacancyId
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("QuestionBlocks", "Questions")',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify(model),
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: false,
        success: function (data) {
            var question1 = data[0]

            $(".list").append('<div   id="something" style="cursor: pointer;width:80%;font-size:20px;margin-top:15px;border-style: solid;border-color:#ffcf00;border-radius: 5px;margin: 10px auto 0;;">' + question1.Question1 + '</div>' + '<div  id="something" style="width:80%;font-size:20px;margin-top:15px;border-style: solid;border-color: #ffcf00;border-radius: 5px;margin: 10px auto 0;">' + question1.Question2 + '</div>' + '<div class="testing666" id="something" style="width:80%;font-size:20px;margin-top:15px;border-style: solid;border-color: #ffcf00;border-radius: 5px;margin: 10px auto 0;">' + question1.Question3 + '</div>' + '<div class="testing666" id="something" style="width:80%;font-size:20px;margin-top:15px;border-style: solid;border-color: #ffcf00;border-radius: 5px;margin: 10px auto 0;">' + question1.Question4 + '</div>' + '<div class="testing666" id="something" style="width:80%;font-size:20px;margin-top:15px;border-style: solid;border-color: #ffcf00;border-radius: 5px;margin: 10px auto 0;">' + question1.Question5 + '</div>' + '<div class="testing666" id="something" style="width:80%;font-size:20px;margin-top:15px;border-style: solid;border-color: #ffcf00;border-radius: 5px;margin: 10px auto 0;">' + question1.Question6 + '</div>' + '<div class="testing666" id="something" style="width:80%;font-size:20px;margin-top:15px;border-style: solid;border-color: #ffcf00;border-radius: 5px;margin: 10px auto 0;">' + question1.Question7 + '</div>' + '<div class="testing666" id="something" style="width:80%;font-size:20px;margin-top:15px;border-style: solid;border-color: #ffcf00;border-radius: 5px;margin: 10px auto 0;">' + question1.Question8 + '</div>' + '<div class="testing666" id="something" style="width:80%;font-size:20px;margin-top:15px;border-style: solid;border-color: #ffcf00;border-radius: 5px;margin: 10px auto 0;">' + question1.Question9 + '</div>' + '<div class="testing666" id="something" style="width:80%;font-size:20px;margin-top:15px;border-style: solid;border-color: #ffcf00;border-radius: 5px;margin: 10px auto 0;">' + question1.Question10 + '</div>');
            var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

            for (i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
                if (divs[i].innerHTML == "") {
                    divs[i].style.display = 'none';
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

In other script I need to get value from div with id  =  something.

But my problem in that I can have many divs with id  = something.

How I can get value via position or something?

**UPDATE**

Now I have this script to get value but it not works correctly (here is part of script)

```
$(document).on('click', '.something', function () {
   // alert("Gotcha!!!");
    //$(".videolist").empty();
    var vacancyId = $(".something").text();
   alert(vacancyId);
```

Comment: Don't have multiple elements on the same page with the same id, use class for that

Comment: Okay, how I can change code do generate it with id + 1 for example?@CarstenLøvboAndersen

Comment: @EugeneSukhomlyn don't use incremental `id` attributes - thats just adding more needless complexity. Use common classes instead

Comment: Okay, change `id` to `class`, but now I have many elements with same classes @AlivetoDie

Comment: Well you are leaving out if you want the value of all element by the class or a specific one And how you want to get the value,(click event or ?

Comment: I need to get value of specific one. by click event@CarstenLøvboAndersen

Comment: I will updatequestion now@CarstenLøvboAndersen

Comment: @EugeneSukhomlyn  use `class` and then use `this` like `$(document).on('click','.something',function(){alert($(this).text();)});`

Comment: Inside your click event try `var v = $(this).text()` now `v` should be the value of your div.

Comment: Thank's dudes, will try now.

Comment: Your solution works. Thank's@CarstenLøvboAndersen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.Convert `id="something"` to `class="something"`

2.convert code like below:-

```
$(document).on('click', '.something', function () {
   var vacancyId = $(this).text();
   alert(vacancyId);
});
```

Comment: @EugeneSukhomlyn  glad to help you:):)

Answer (score 2):

you should not use id. You can use class. İf you use class you will get list. 
and you can take values from list with a loop. just like this

```
     var Values = $('.something');
     var newValue; 

    for (var j = 0; j < Values.length; j++) {

               newvalue=Values[j].text;

            }
    // Or take value that you want
      newValue=Values[5].text;

your function is should be just like this

$(document).on('click', '.something', function () {
   // alert("Gotcha!!!");
    //$(".videolist").empty();
    var vacancyId = $(this).text();
   alert(vacancyId);
```